# Finding the position of a word in string

Tags: r, stringr

```
text = "the nurse was very helpful indeed"
```

I want to search for "very" and then extract "very" and one word after "very"

the output should be : `very helpful`

I used :

```
word(text, start = 4, end= 5 sep = fixed(" "))
```

The is helpful for extracting but I am unable to get the value dynamically for position of the word in the string which is "4" in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `str_extract` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(text, "very\\s+\\w+")
```

---

Or with `regexpr/regmatches` from `base R`

```
regmatches(text, regexpr("very\\s+\\w+", text))
```